# Create pandas column with tree information

Tags: python, pandas

I've a pandas df with the column '`Tree`', and I'd like to create the column '`Leaf`' which only contains `integers`, differentiating if that taxonomy belongs to the same final leaf:

```
'index'    'Tree'
0          'woman | watches | steal'
1          'woman | dresses | short-sleve'
2          'woman | watches | steal'
3          'woman | dresses | short-sleve'
4          'woman | dresses | long-sleve'
```

Output:

```
'index'    'Tree'                            'Leaf' 
0          'woman | watches | steal'          0
1          'woman | dresses | short-sleve'    1
2          'woman | watches | steal'          0 
3          'woman | dresses | short-sleve'    1
4          'woman | dresses | long-sleve'     2
```

Any suggestions how to do it fast?

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby('Tree')` and take the group number:

```
df['Leaf'] = df.groupby('Tree').ngroup()
```

If you want to use only the final element:

```
df['Leaf'] = df.groupby(df['Tree'].str.split(' | ').str[-1]).ngroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to determine the category by the last element of the string that's delimited by pipes. You can extract the relevant information by splitting the `Tree` column:

```py
df['Leaf'] = df.Tree.str.split('|').str[-1]
```

**Preliminary result**

```py
                            Tree          Leaf
0        woman | watches | steal         steal
1  woman | dresses | short-sleve   short-sleve
2        woman | watches | steal         steal
3  woman | dresses | short-sleve   short-sleve
4   woman | dresses | long-sleve    long-sleve
```

Then turn that into categorical:

```py
df['Leaf'] = df.Leaf.astype('category').cat.codes
```

```py
                            Tree  Leaf
0        woman | watches | steal     2
1  woman | dresses | short-sleve     1
2        woman | watches | steal     2
3  woman | dresses | short-sleve     1
4   woman | dresses | long-sleve     0
```